# How has a WhatsApp contact removed our older conversations from my phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I’m baffled . All my previous conversations with one WhatsApp contact are no longer in our WhatsApp chat. They have all been wiped off preceding April 2019. I cannot retrieve from the archive either. I’m confident it is not something I have done, and this contact has erased them somehow on his ph7 WhatsApp. I’m really curious as to how this can be done?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for anybody to delete old WhatsApp conversations from your phone without having access to your phone. The only exception is the short time period during which the sender can retract his message (s).  Even that option will leave a note on your side saying that *This mesaage was deleted*.

It is very likely a case of somebody else accessing your device and deleting the older conversation from your side. Some people have previously used WhatsApp web interface to access the chats of others without their knowledge. But even for this the user needs to scan the WhatsApp Web QR code using your mobile phone. You can check for active WhatsApp Web sessions by:

Open WhatsApp > Tap on 3 dots at top right > WhatsApp Web.